# Get folder path within c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, directory

I am trying to retrieve folder flags that is within my aplication like shown in printscreen how do i do that

[image]

I tried the below code but doesnt work for me as it gives me c:\ location whereas my project is in d drive

```
   private void Countryflag_SelectionChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        PowerPoint.SlideRange ppslr = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange;
        string id = Countryflag.SelectedItem.Label;
        int countlargest = ppslr.Shapes.Count;
        PowerPoint.Shape shapepic = ppslr.Shapes[countlargest];


        String programfilesPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
           // Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
        //String msOfficePath = "Microsoft Office\\Document Themes 14";
        String msOfficePath = "~\\NepaAddintool\\Flag\\allflags\\";
        String fullPath = Path.Combine(programfilesPath, msOfficePath);
        string imagename = id + ".gif";

        String themePresentationPath = fullPath + "\\" + imagename;

       // ppslr.Shapes.AddPicture(themePresentationPath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, shapepic.Left, shapepic.Top, shapepic.Width, shapepic.Height);
      ppslr.Shapes.AddPicture(themePresentationPath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 803, 35, 86, 56);
    }
```

Comment: Are these resources to your project? It may be better to just reference them as resources than trying to mess around with image folders

Comment: If this is an office add-in, it works within parent office application only, so it may return path of the office installation, Besides, if these images are marked as `resource` / `embedded resource` or they are not set to `copy to output directory`, they will not be available on deployment folder.

Comment: @mcy: how do i work with it its office add-in and i need to call this folder even after deploying

Comment: @test if you only need the images in your code, you can (and possibly should) mark them as `resource`; by this way, they will not be copied to deployment folder but you will be able to reach them irrelevant of their location https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try adding the image older path in config,

```
 <add key="CommonImageFolder" value="D:/NepaAddintool/Flag/allflags" />
```

and then access it in ur app like,

```
 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommonImageFolder"];
```

instead of msOfficePath.

Comment: im using office interop so i dont have config file